# Switch on/off NSLog with a boolean just like CCLog in cocos2d

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocos2d-iphone, uikit

I have a IS_TESTING boolean flag indicating whether the current build is testing

I want to hide NSLog if IS_TESTING is NO. And it should also support a single string parameter.

This is CCLog from cocos2d:

```
#define __CCLOGWITHFUNCTION(s, ...) \
NSLog(@"%s : %@",__FUNCTION__,[NSString stringWithFormat:(s), ##__VA_ARGS__])

#define __CCLOG(s, ...) \
NSLog(@"%@",[NSString stringWithFormat:(s), ##__VA_ARGS__])


#if !defined(COCOS2D_DEBUG) || COCOS2D_DEBUG == 0
#define CCLOG(...) do {} while (0)
#define CCLOGWARN(...) do {} while (0)
#define CCLOGINFO(...) do {} while (0)

#elif COCOS2D_DEBUG == 1
#define CCLOG(...) __CCLOG(__VA_ARGS__)
#define CCLOGWARN(...) __CCLOGWITHFUNCTION(__VA_ARGS__)
#define CCLOGINFO(...) do {} while (0)

#elif COCOS2D_DEBUG > 1
#define CCLOG(...) __CCLOG(__VA_ARGS__)
#define CCLOGWARN(...) __CCLOGWITHFUNCTION(__VA_ARGS__)
#define CCLOGINFO(...) __CCLOG(__VA_ARGS__)
#endif // COCOS2D_DEBUG
```

This is what I write:

```
#define __CCLOG(s, ...) \
NSLog(@"%@",[NSString stringWithFormat:(s), ##__VA_ARGS__])


#if IS_TESTING == 0
#define CCLOG(...) do {} while (0)

#elif IS_TESTING == 1
#define CCLOG(...) __CCLOG(__VA_ARGS__)

#endif
```

use:

```
CCLOG(@"single string parameter");
CCLOG(@"string format %@", @"parameter");
```

It runs without crash, but nothing gets printed out.

EDIT:

```
#define IS_TESTING YES
```

I have tried 
    `#if IS_TESTING == YES/NO`, but still the same as 0/1, nothing gets printed out

Comment: FWIW, Xcode has a defined "DEBUG", which is defined as 1 and then automatically changed to being defined as 0 for release builds.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works perfectly. But `IS_TESTING` must be defined *before* you start the `__CCLOG` definition stuff.

So, in the *.pch* file, I wrote:

```
#define IS_TESTING 1

#define __CCLOG(s, ...) \
NSLog(@"%@",[NSString stringWithFormat:(s), ##__VA_ARGS__])

#if IS_TESTING == 0
#define CCLOG(...) do {} while (0)
#elif IS_TESTING == 1
#define CCLOG(...) __CCLOG(__VA_ARGS__)
#endif
```

And later:

```
CCLOG(@"%@", @"YES");
```

Since I have defined `IS_TESTING` to 1, we log. If I change it to 0, we don't.

---

As a bonus, I'll show you what I do. It's much simpler. Here it is:

```
#define MyLog if(0); else NSLog
```

This makes `MyLog` equivalent to `NSLog`. To turn off logging, change `0` to `1`.

Comment: NSLog does not support single string param. so you have to do NSLog(@"%@", @"a string")

Comment: is it possible to define IS_TESTING as YES instead of 1?